# Differences in sending a multipart/form-data post via requests

Tags: python, file, python-requests, send

I've got problem while trying to post the file to the server. I'm trying to make file upload script to server, this server is very 'Sensitive to correctness post request'

I debugged page that is sending the file to server and browser send this (TextView):

```
POST http://example.com/post HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 20625
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Origin: http://example.com
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.104 Safari/537.36
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=----WebKitFormBoundarykGHBkXoER9gNuVna
Referer: http://example.com/foo
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: pl-PL,pl;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4,pt;q=0.2

------WebKitFormBoundarykGHBkXoER9gNuVna
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="file.zip"
Content-Type: application/octet-stream

...raw file data...

------WebKitFormBoundarykGHBkXoER9gNuVna--
```

However, my script is sending this (TextView):

```
POST http://example.com/post HTTP/1.1
Host: example.com
Connection: keep-alive
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept: */*
User-Agent: python-requests/2.18.1
Content-Length: 20604

--f8c266cf436941019c5a80c7d4779a57
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="files[]"; filename="file.zip"
Content-Type: application/zip

...raw file data...

--f8c266cf436941019c5a80c7d4779a57--
```

With causes error on server, additional note: this error started when I changed `files=files` to `data=files`

Current Code:

```
files = MultipartEncoder({'files[]': (filename, open(local_path,'rb'), mimetype)})
UploadFile = requests.post(self.UploadURL, data=files, allow_redirects=False)
```

Working code:

```
files = {'files[]': (filename, open(local_path,'rb'), mimetype)}
UploadFile = requests.post(self.UploadURL, files=files, allow_redirects=False)
```

I'm using `MultipartEncoder` to allow sending huge files.
I see that biggest mismatch is "boundary", but why this 'boundary' is generating in `working code` but in `Current code` not?

How to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not setting the `Content-Type` header, the `MultipartEncoder` provides it for you:

```
files = MultipartEncoder({'files[]': (filename, open(local_path,'rb'), mimetype)})
UploadFile = requests.post(
    self.UploadURL, data=files, allow_redirects=False,
    headers={'Content-Type': files.content_type})
```

The header must come from the multi-part encoding, because it is responsible for picking the *boundary* used to deliniate the various MIME parts in the multipart response. In your upload that's:

```
--f8c266cf436941019c5a80c7d4779a57
```

but it is generated at random each time your code runs. The header provided would look like:

```
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=--f8c266cf436941019c5a80c7d4779a57
```